# How is "preferred" to be understood in Apple developer downloads

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk

In Apple developer downloads, some downloads are marked with "preferred". I have not been able to find anything that covers what this means. Does it mean that we as developers should switch to this version now?

[image: Apple preferred download]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes,** this mark means that the particular beta is the last version and developers should switch to it.

You can find a detailed changelog for iOS 11 beta 3 [here](https://download.developer.apple.com/Documentation/Beta_Release_Notes_Jul_10_2017/iOS_11_beta_3_Release_Notes.pdf) (developer login required).

Comment: Thank you. But this raises yet another question. To develop for iOS 11 beta 3 you need the beta of xcode, this makes sense. But the beta of xcode is not marked "preferred" which seems kind of inconsistent to me.

Comment: @iCediCe This also seems to be an inconsistency for me. Maybe the indicator only shows the preferred operating systems and not IDEs.